# :search => :all return empty on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

i have a link_to like this:

```
<%= link_to "All", cars_path(:search => :all) %>
```

When i click him i receive this url:

localhost:3000/cars?search=all

The issue is, i have 3 records in database and don't appears nothing with the search link.

My cars_controller.rb have on index:

```
@cars = Car.search(params[:search])
```

And in the car.rb model i have a method:

```
def self.search(search)
    result = order('new DESC')
    result = joins(:model => :brand).where('brands.title LIKE ? OR models.title LIKE ? OR status LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%").order('new DESC') if search.present?
    result
end
```

I have another methods, but i delimited to this and still not working.

Any suggestions are welcome, thank you!

Comment: What is the result of `result.to_sql`?

Comment: I received in the log this: https://gist.github.com/stanmx/ce89c3f1703676094fdb

Comment: Do I have to point the problem for you? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query you are searching for an car that has 'all' in its title or brand name. Is that really what you want? And do you have any cars in your table with such name?

If you just write `<%= link_to "All", cars_path %>` search won't be present and you should get all cars.

When you are using same params multiply times in an query like this you can make it much shorter if you write it like this.

```
def self.search(search)
    result = order('new DESC')
    result = result.joins(:model => :brand).where('brands.title LIKE :search OR models.title LIKE :search OR status LIKE :search', search: "%#{search}%") if search.present?
    result
end
```